# Timespan return wrong value

Tags: c#, timespan

I have an application that has multiple languages. I'm having a problem that I convert the date from the USA standard to the one we use in Brazil, I'm using this.

```
DateTime dataCredito = DateTime.Parse(txtDtCredito.Text);
if (Culture == "English (United States)")
{
    string dataConvertida = dataCredito.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dataCredito = Convert.ToDateTime(dataConvertida);
}
```

But after I calculate a time span

```
 TimeSpan ts = dataNota - dataCredito;
```

The `dataNota` is 09/10/2016 
and `dataCredito` is 05/10/2016

It's a 4 day difference, but the timespan is calculating the method as the month is 05 and 09, the diferrence is about 123 days, using the USA standard.

How can I change this to get the time span correctly (4 days for this case)?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? ```string dataConvertida = dataCredito.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dataCredito = Convert.ToDateTime(dataConvertida);``` This is not a make sense

Comment: The issue isn't with `TimeSpan` it's with the parsing of the string to `DateTime`.

Comment: What is the default culture of your app? Because you're parsing the date without inform what culture the `DateTime.Parse` should use.

Comment: I add  a answer,i just convert back to USA standard to calculate the timespan.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you convert text to a DateTime object. by not notifying the method, how you want it converted - you implicitly allowed the conversion to be done based on your own locale, when you should have explicitly stated the format this way:

```
DateTime dataCredito = DateTime.ParseExact("09/10/2016","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

obviously you should replace "09/10/2016" with your text input, if you need support for single digits use "d/M/yyyy" formatting instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse a `DateTime` correctly, you need to use the `DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` overload of `DateTime.Parse()`.

The same applies when you are trying to parse any other data type with culture-specific representation.

Answer (score -3):

I Managed to fix this.

I Just add this before the timespan,now the timespan is return the correct 4.

```
if (Culture == "English (United States)")
                    {
                       string dataAmericana = dataCredito.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                       dataCredito = Convert.ToDateTime(dataAmericana);
                       string dataNotaNova = dataNota.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        dataNota = Convert.ToDateTime(dataNotaNova);
                    }
                    TimeSpan ts = dataNota - dataCredito;
```

Comment: That is nonsense.  There is nothing gained by converting dates to strings back to dates.  Dates do not have a format.  Use the mouse to examine `dataCredito` before and after the gyrations you will see it is the same value

Comment: How is this nonsense if this Works? dataCredito  is 05/10/2016,after this conversion it become 10/05/2016,this is what is asked in the question.